# RS232 Port Errors on Windows 7

Tags: windows, testing, serial-port, hardware

We are trying to hook up a Hanwa ESD Simulator to a Windows 7 machine. on the Hanwa GUI, when we click on 'Start Test', we are getting the following error.

[image]

1. We changed RS232 cable: Error persists
2. We verified that the ESD Simulator was turned on and connected.
3. We configured the port in the Device manager.

[image]

4. We re-installed all driver software: issue still persists.
5. We tried different ports: issue still persists.

Do you know how we can solve this error?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first thing I would do is put a loopback wire between pins 2 & 3 on the PC connector and then open the serial port using a terminal program like [Brays Terminal](https://sites.google.com/site/terminalbpp/).

This will make sure you are using the correct serial port and that it is capable of transmitting and receiving.

When that works I would connect the ESD Simulator and look in the manual to confirm/set communications parameters in Bray's terminal and look for a simple command with response to see if the ESD simulator can read and write characters. If not, you have to determine if it is a cable handshaking issue or faulty equipment.